# Finding the first specific value above a certain cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a way to find the first specific value above a certain cell.
Using the example below, in the result column every time I hit a A in COL2, I need to substract the value in COL1 to the first A value above.

The trouble seems  finding a way to keep the range dynamic...
I thought of `=IF(B5="A";A5-INDIRECT("A"&MATCH("A";B:B;0));"")`

But of course that only works for the first one as Match will always pick up the first one.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Example :

```
COL1    COL2    Result
1       A   
2       0
3       0
4       A       4 - 1 = 3
5       0
6       A       6 - 4 = 2
7       0
8       0
9       0
10      A       10 - 6 = 4
```

Comment: Would you be willing to add a column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(AND(ROW(B2)<>2,B2="A"),A2-INDEX($A$1:$A1,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($1:1)/($B$1:$B1="A"),1)),"")
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

The AGGREGATE() Function was introduced in 2010.

Comment: Awesome! Didn't know aggregate() until now.

Answer (score 0):

- In D2 enter `=IF(B2="A",A2-INDIRECT("A"&MATCH("A"&(E2-1),F:F,0)),"")`
- In E2 enter `=IF(B2="a",COUNTIFS($B$2:B2,"a"),"")`
- In F2 enter `=B2&E2`
- Copy formulas from D, E and F down all your rows

Column D is the result you're looking for